# How do I use FB.getLoginStatus() on page load if Parse.com handles init?

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

[Documentation for `Parse.FacebookUtils.init()`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.FacebookUtils.html#.init) states:

> The status flag will be coerced to 'false' because it interferes with Parse Facebook integration. Call FB.getLoginStatus() explicitly if this behavior is required by your application.

Unfortunately, when I try to call `FB.getLoginStatus()`, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLoginStatus' of undefined`. Is there either a callback that I can use to know when `FB` is loaded, or some other way to check the login status of a user on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using promises to resolve FB after it's loaded.

```
var fbDeferred = $q.defer();

$window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxx',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.2'
  });
  fbDeferred.resolve(FB);
};

var getFB = function(){
  return fbDeferred.promise;
}

var getFBLoginStatus = function(){
  return getFB().then(function(FB){

    //**FB is now available**

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 'connected'){
        ...
      }else{
        ...
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see some code, it sounds like the SDK hasn't loaded when you call getLoginStatus().

Anyway this may help, I took [Facebook's basic Login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4) and added Parse around it. It checks when the DOM is loaded so you could use some of this logic also.
[Simple Facebook Login test with Parse](http://maybe-fb-raw-parse.herokuapp.com/) - view source

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your "View source" text isn't linked.